# Sharing content between two windows at the same time

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to have the content of two windows be shared, but it doesn't seem to be working as i would expect.

Here is a simple example showing this:

```
class TestClass
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application app = new Application();

        TextBox t = new TextBox();
        t.Text = "test";

        Window w1 = new Window();
        w1.Content = t;
        w1.Show();

        Window w2 = new Window();
        w2.Content = t;
        w2.Show();


        app.Run();
    }
}
```

If i step through the program in debug mode, i can see that `w1` has the textbox, but as soon as the call `w2.Content = t;` then `w1` loses the textbox... and it then shows up in only `w2`.

I also tried using binding in Xmal, where both windows pointed to the same ViewModel (with a property named MySharedContent)

`Content="{Binding Path=MySharedContent}"`

but it doesn't work.

Is this possible? Am i doing something stupid? I was thinking that both windows would have a pointer to the content for rendering... but it almost seems like they can't share the same instance?

EDIT:

So the basic answer is that a UI element (textbox, usercontrol, etc) can only have 1 parent. Thus i need to have two separate UI elements that share the same associated data. Got it (thanks everyone for the help, up-votes for everyone)

Comment: UI controls typically can only be the child of one element.

Comment: is there a way around it?
for the above example, am i forced to just have two separate textboxes that both bind to the same string value for their text?

Comment: That would be the appropriate reaction. The control itself is not shared; the text is semantically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controls have a `Parent` property which returns the container they have been placed in. Therefore and because each `TextBox` needs to have its own set of properties like its size and location, your approach cannot work. You can share the value (the string `"test"` in your case) displayed by the `TextBoxes` in the two windows, but not the `TextBoxes` themselves.

Create two Textboxes!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the control's parent container gets updated on assignment, creating that behaviour (though I'd have assumed the same as you initially too).

What're you trying to do?  You could pass a string variable if you want the two windows to be in sync; using this value to update the textbox in each alternate window.

Comment: My actual code is very different windows, that have a shared (complicated) usercontrol inside each of them... this usercontrol also can be replaced with a different usercontrol... and i wanted each window to have a ContextControl who's data was bound to the current usercontrol class.
Am i forced to make 2 instances of the same usercontrol, and bind the text/images/etc within each of them?

Comment: I'm not 100% on this, but I suspect there's no way to have the same instance of the control in both windows at the same time.  Another workaround may be to have the control switch contexts - i.e. pass a reference of the control to each window, which hold this control reference in a variable, then on getting focus the window adds the control to its controls collection?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to do the handling in the applications main you have have to do it in each forms event handlers.

Textbox example; In `Form1` we have `MyTextBox` in `Form2` we also have my `MyTextBox` which is equivalent. In both forms I have an event handler for when the text changes. If the event handler is invoked in `Form1` I set `Form2.MyTextBox.Text = Form1.MyTextBox.Text;` and do the inverse in Form2's event handler.

Do this in all the event handlers and the forms will mirror each other.

Comment: I think the difference here is that the photo isn't a UI element, like a textbox.

Comment: right, but you are just changing the text within the textbox, not a copy of the UI element (textbox) itself.

Comment: @00jt Yeah. My suggestion is more of a work around than a solution.